# Creating a User Queue for Page Access?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, queue

BASIC GOALS:
I have page that I only want one person to be able to view at a time. I need to create a queue that will let each new user know how long (wait time) it is until they can access the page and how many people are in front of them.

Comment: Any Stack Overflow question that could be phrased with "Dear Diary," at the start is off-topic and will probably be closed. What code do you have? What database structure are you working with? **What have you tried?**

Comment: first am new to this community so sorry if i make any mistake
this is an experimental project i am learning php and mysql so i need some script to work with

Comment: `i need some script to work with` - SO is not a code writing service either

Comment: It's alright to be learning, don't get me wrong, but this is a question that's way too vague to fit the format here. It's simply in the wrong place. Just as you may have a legitimate question about gardening, you need to find the right forum. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com).